# Putting a function to a local namespace to speeding up access taking descriptors into account

Tags: python, descriptor

I use `numpy.random.normal` function in a **tough** loop in a class.

```
class MyClass(MyBaseClass):   
    def run(self):
        while True:
            ...
            self.L.append(numpy.random.normal(0,1))
```

I know that it's pretty slow in Python to use multiple lookups. In `numpy.random.normal` there are 3 lookups: first `numpy` is looked up, then `random`, and then `normal`.

So I decided to address this problem by assigning `numpy.random.normal` to a local variable `_normal`.

Here we go:

```
class MyClass(MyBaseClass):
    _normal = numpy.random.normal
    def run(self):
        while True:
            ...
            self.L.append(MyClass._normal(0,1))
```

What I'm really concerned about is descriptors. When a variable in a class in accessed, all the bases classes are looked up for the **data descriptor** with the same name. It's described [here](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#attribute-search-summary):

> Check `objectname.__class__.__dict__`for attrname. If it exists and is a data-descriptor, return the descriptor result. Search all bases of `objectname.__class__` for the same case.

So, I guess, if I put `_normal` in the local space as I did above, it will case looking up all bases classes for the data descriptor. And I wary of it becoming a source of a slowdown.

Are my concerns justified?

Should I worry about the time it takes to look up for the descriptors in base classes?

And is there a better way to speed up access to a function located deep into a module when it's used in a class?

---

There was a discussion in the comments to the answers.

I decided to give some additional details of implementation that appeared to be important (for my particular case).

Actually, the code is closer to this (it's very very simplified):

```
class MyClass(MyBaseClass):

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        self.L.append(numpy.random.normal(0,1))   

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.next()
```

Comment: That article seems fishy, mostly because it has no mention of `_getattr__`, `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` and because it seems to say that class attributes always take precedence over instance attributes (which is clearly not the case). I'd stick to the official documentation.

Comment: @delnan In this case I think it's particularly important to lay out all it in the answer.

Comment: @delnan: in the case of descriptors, class "attributes" *do* take precedence over instance attributes.  The resolution order is descriptors first, then instance attributes, and finally class attributes.  For this reason, it's unusual to even have instance attributes when a descriptor is present, the descriptor will normally prevent the instance attribute from ever being assigned.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Thanks for prompting me to re-check, I missed the "and is a data descriptor" part in step 2. Now it makes slightly more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you must do something like this (is function lookup actually the dominant cost?  Random number generation is not cheap) you should realize that one global + one attr lookup (`MyClass._normal`) is not that much cheaper than one global + three attr lookups (`numpy.random.normal`).  What you really want is to get *zero* global or attr lookups inside the loop, which you can only do by defining `_normal` *inside the function*. If you're really desperate to shave cycles you should also prebind the list append call:

```
class MyClass(MyBaseClass):
    def run(self):
        _normal = numpy.random.normal
        _Lappend = self.L.append
        while True:
            ...
            _Lappend(_normal(0,1))
```

Contrast disassembly output (just for the `append` statement):

```
  LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
  LOAD_ATTR                1 (L)
  LOAD_ATTR                2 (append)
  LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (numpy)
  LOAD_ATTR                4 (random)
  LOAD_ATTR                5 (normal)
  LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
  LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
  CALL_FUNCTION            2
  CALL_FUNCTION            1
  POP_TOP
```

vs

```
  LOAD_FAST                2 (_Lappend)
  LOAD_FAST                1 (_normal)
  LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
  LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
  CALL_FUNCTION            2
  CALL_FUNCTION            1
```

What would be even better is to vectorize -- generate many random normal deviates from and append them to the list in one go -- you can do that with the `size` argument to `numpy.random.normal`.

Comment: My only concern was that random generator is written in C and it's fast, and all those lookup are made by Python and they are pretty slow. I very well remember [the article](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html) by Guido Van Rossum where he points out how costly may lookups be.

Comment: > one global + three attr lookups: But in this case this global lookup is actually is very costly, because this lookup is looking all the bases for the satisfactory descriptor.

Comment: And in my particular case (I didn't reflect it in the question) `_normal` was located in the other method, called `next`. There was a `run` method, but it called `next` in a tough loop. I thought it was a redundant detail for the question, but it seems to be not. Because if I create a function in `next` method and locate `_normal` and `_Lappend` in it, nothing will change, since it calls `_normal` only once and putting `normal` to a local namespace actually has to do one search for `normal` which can be made directly.

Comment: @ovgolovin: (1) The lookups are also written in C (though they operate on Python objects, the random number generator also needs to create a Python object). (2) The global lookup won't look through base classes, only the attribute lookups (*all* of them) *may* do so. (3) You're optimizing for performance yet you didn't consider inlining trivial methods? Method calls are even more complicated (attr lookup + bound method object creation + frame setup + possibly extra opcodes + missed peephole optimizations).

Comment: @delnan may be it's better to put `_normal` into `global` namespace? Or maybe I exaggerating and all those descriptor search procedures are quite fast? Then what about the article by Giudo Van Rossum I mentioned in the first comment?

Comment: @delnan About (3). You are right. But at least if I create a rule for myself about at least how to effectively use those functions located deep in modules, it would be very good and there will be minus one thing to contemplate on when writing code.

Comment: @ovgolovin: That article has different conclusions (IIRC it doesn't even touch on attribute access), like "push loops into C" and "avoid calling Python functions frequently for tiny amounts of work". And those hold.

Comment: For now I decided for myself to put function into local namespace of the function with a tough loop, or put it into global namespace if the former is not possible (like in my actual case when a tough loop is started in another method then where `_normal` is actually called)

Comment: I updated the question. Now I see that it's very important to put `self.next` into local namespace of  `run` method. And as regards `_norma` it seems the only option to be is to put `_normal` to `global` namespace. Are my ideas correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way! It unveiled a lot of things for me.

Answer (score 2):

> And I wary of it becoming a source of a slowdown.
>
> Are my concerns justified?

That depends.  Is it already fast enough for the application you have in mind?  If so, don't fret.  Changes in CPython, PyPy, NumPy and moore's law are likely to mitigate the magnitude of the "slowdown" before it becomes a sticking point.

Comment: But moore's law will positively influence the more effective code as well. In fact, my project where I used this is over. And that was a one-off 1 minute code run. So there is no problem now. But I want to teach myself a good code practice. And this is a good opportunity to learn how to address such problems discussed in the question.

Comment: Why I'm actually asking is that they may be some ready checked over time solutions. It may be even better to put `_normal` to global namespace than to class namespace. So, I'm asking in hope somebody has the answer or suggestions.

Comment: PyPy will optimize that away though. Those optimizations are completely pointless in PyPy.